# Compare grouped rows with grouped rows at the next different row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'block': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                   'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'C': [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000],
                   })
```

Which outputs:

```
  block  B     C
0     1  a  1000
1     1  b  2000
2     1  c  3000
3     2  a  4000
4     2  b  5000
5     2  c  6000
6     3  a  7000
7     3  b  8000
8     3  c  9000
```

I want to output a `diff_column` (could also be an entirely `new_df`) who's values are the difference between the values in the `C` column grouped by the `B` column for every different value in the `block` column.

That is, what's the difference between `a`'s value in `block` 2 and `a`'s value in `block` 1?

Example for `a`:

```
4000 - 1000 = 3000
```

Note, the rows for `block` == 1 would be empty since there is no other previous `block`.

I have tried:

```
df['diff_column'] = df.groupby(['block', 'B'])['C'] - df.shift[-1].groupby(['block', 'B'])['C']
```

with no success.

Comment: How looks expected ouput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the blocks are sorted, you can use [`groupby.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with column B as grouper:

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('B')['C'].diff()
```

With [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) as you initially tried to do:

```
df['diff'] = df['C']-df.groupby('B')['C'].shift()
```

output:

```
   block  B     C    diff
0      1  a  1000     NaN
1      1  b  2000     NaN
2      1  c  3000     NaN
3      2  a  4000  3000.0  # block 2/a - block 1/a
4      2  b  5000  3000.0
5      2  c  6000  3000.0
6      3  a  7000  3000.0
7      3  b  8000  3000.0
8      3  c  9000  3000.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is there no need to specify column `block` anywhere? I'm assuming this has to do with your assumption that `block` is indeed sorted. Blocks will always increase from top to bottom.

Comment: Because if you group by block, you won't have values to compare (all your groups will be 1 item). Try to run `list(df.groupby('B'))` to see the groups. The `block` is implicitly there due to the order of the rows ;)

Comment: `diff()` is the even better solution. Thanks for reminding mozway :-)

Comment: Thanks guys! What if I have even more columns I want to group by, instead of just column B? Will it calculate the difference between those groupings between the blocks too?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do:

```
# group by 'B' and use shift(1) to get previous value, then subtract from 'C' only
df["diff_column"] = df["C"] - df.groupby(["B"])["C"].shift(1)

+----+---------+-----+------+---------------+
|    |   block | B   |    C |   diff_column |
|----+---------+-----+------+---------------|
|  0 |       1 | a   | 1000 |           nan |
|  1 |       1 | b   | 2000 |           nan |
|  2 |       1 | c   | 3000 |           nan |
|  3 |       2 | a   | 4000 |          3000 |
|  4 |       2 | b   | 5000 |          3000 |
|  5 |       2 | c   | 6000 |          3000 |
|  6 |       3 | a   | 7000 |          3000 |
|  7 |       3 | b   | 8000 |          3000 |
|  8 |       3 | c   | 9000 |          3000 |
+----+---------+-----+------+---------------+
```